# Implement 'filtering'

Tags: haskell

The NICTA Haskell [Course](https://github.com/NICTA/course) presents the following function to implement on `List`:

```
data List t =
  Nil
  | t :. List t
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

And the function:

```
filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)
filtering _ Nil       = pure Nil
filtering f (x :. xs) = (++) <$> ((\y -> case y of True -> x :. Nil
                                                   False -> Nil) <$> f x) <*>   
                                                         filtering f xs
```

Please review this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the course materials, I think you've missed the point. [Applicative.hs](https://github.com/NICTA/course/blob/master/src/Course/Applicative.hs) has you define `sequence :: Applicative f => List (f a) -> f (List a)` before `filtering`, and looking briefly through the [suggested progression](https://github.com/NICTA/course#progression) it appears as though things are ordered such that there is always a “clever” answer to be built out of the things you've previously implemented.

That said, this question then gets both easier and harder. Easier because there is purpose built machinery to manipulate e.g. that weird non-Prelude `List` type. Harder because this isn't really standard Haskell anymore since all of our usual functions and typeclasses have been replaced by their evil twins.

I think the intended answer is that you map the predicate function over the list you're given, then use the `sequence` function you defined earlier to switch `List (f Bool)` to `f (List Bool)`, then... I dunno. This is mirror world.

Here's how you'd write this function given the types from regular old `base`.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable

filtering :: (Applicative f) => (a -> f Bool) -> [a] -> f [a]
filtering f xs = (xs `filterBy`) <$> (sequenceA . map f $ xs)
    where
        filterBy :: [a] -> [Bool] -> [a]
        filterBy xs ps = map fst . filter snd $ zip xs ps
```

I assume the version you're looking for will be identical, but using `sequence` instead of `sequenceA`.

---

I think there is probably an even more clever solution—and I suspect it uses the reader instance (`((->) a)`) and a lifted `filter`—but I sure can't tease it out. Comments and edits welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that stand out to me:

1. The use of `(++)`. (Probably minor since the first list is guaranteed to have at most one element.)
2. Using a `case` over a `Bool`.

Let’s look at the second one first. You can replace a `case` over a `Bool` with an `if`:

```
case y of True -> x :. Nil    ===>    if y then x :. Nil
          False -> Nil                     else Nil
```

Or, since it’s in a lambda, it might be more concise to continue to use `case`, but with `LambdaCase` notation:

```
                                            {-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
\y -> case y of True -> x :. Nil    ===>    \case True  -> x :. Nil
                False -> Nil                      False ->      Nil
```

The other thing that stood out was the use of `(++)`. I think that rather than creating a list and prepending that to the recursive part, you might want to consider creating a function that either prepends an element or returns its argument, and apply that to the recursive part. Then you will have no use of `(++)`:

```
($) <$> (\case True  -> (x :.)
               False -> id) <*> filtering f xs
```